# How to Enable Brightness Buttons when acpi_osi of Grub not enough in Debian of Zenbook?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, brightness, zenbook

- Initial condition: brightness-control buttons do not work, no animation of brightness-control not seen on actions, but manual control of brightness work in Settings and at the top-bar.
- Condition after test code 1: brightness-control buttons do not affect brightness but visual animation is shown after reboot; however, now, the manual control of brightness do not work anymore so the solution which works in Ubuntu does not work in Debian.

  - I have tried here both `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi="` in `/etc/default/grub` unsuccessfully, where the option without `splash` is the default setting in Debian, in contrast to Ubuntu. The complete default option is only with `quiet` in Debian.

### Differential solutions

1. Use defaults. Undo changes of Test code 1. Weakness: brightness keys do not work but you can control brightness from the top-bar.
2. ?

### Test code 1

I can fix the brightness-control buttons (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> for brightness decrease and increase, respectively) in Ubuntu 16.04 as described in the thread [How to Enable Brightness Buttons when acpi_osi of Grub not enough in 16.04 of Zenbook?](https://askubuntu.com/a/816622/25388) but not in Debian 8.5. 
There is no directory `/usr/share/xorg.conf.d/` in Debian, in contrast to Ubuntu, so possibly similar work flow does not work in Debian. 
Main points done in the following work flow in Debian

1. Add code in `/etc/default/grub`

   ```
   # guillaume-desclaux https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243162
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
   # I also tried here without `splash`, since it did 
   # not exist by default in Debian, in contrast to Ubuntu.
   ```
2. Create directory `/usr/share/xorg.conf.d/`
3. Add the following content in the file `/usr/share/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

   ```
   # https://askubuntu.com/a/536618/25388
   Section "Device"
           Identifier "card0"
           Driver "intel"
           Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
           BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection
   ```
4. Run as root

   ```
   update-grub
   ```

My work flow in Debian

```
root@masi:/home/masi# vim /etc/default/grub 
root@masi:/home/masi# vim /usr/share/x
xfig/      xml/       xml-core/  xsessions/ 
root@masi:/home/masi# mkdir /usr/share/xorg.conf.d/
root@masi:/home/masi# vim /usr/share/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
root@masi:/home/masi# sudo update-grub
bash: sudo: command not found
root@masi:/home/masi# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
root@masi:/home/masi#
```

Output: brightness keys not working after reboot; you now see the visual effect but no effect; after the changes, the brightness control also break if you try to manually change it.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Linux kernel 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No supported and/or sufficient solution exists for the hardware in Debian 8.5.